# Automatically Locate File Path of Other Files

Tags: excel, vba, path

I have an excel script that allows me to select the file path of an Access file through the use of a Dialogue Box and then paste the file path in a specific cell. My code for doing that is like this

```
`Sub selectFile()

Dim wkb As Workbook

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Set wkb = Workbooks("Excel-Access PV Recorder1.xlsm")

Dim dialogBox As FileDialog
Set dialogBox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
dialogBox.AllowMultiSelect = False
'Set the title of of the DialogBox
dialogBox.Title = "Select a file"
'Set the default folder to open
dialogBox.InitialFileName = "C:\Users\Kobby\Documents\Example Folder"
'Clear the dialog box filters
dialogBox.Filters.clear
'Apply file filters - use ; to separate filters for the same name
dialogBox.Filters.Add "Access", "*.accdb"
'Show the dialog box and output full file name
If dialogBox.Show = -1 Then
wkb.Sheets(6).Range("File_Path").Value = dialogBox.SelectedItems(1)
End If
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
ErrHandler:
Debug.Print Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description

End Sub`
```

My question is, is there a way i can get a script that will automatically locate the file path of the Access file and paste the file path in the cell location if i open my excel file without me using the dialogue box even if i should move the folder that contains both the access and excel file to a different location or computer? Just to let you know; i keep the Access file and the Excel file in the same folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i keep the Access file and the Excel file in the same folder.

- Use `Workbook_Open` event to update `File_Path` cell. The code is fired when users open the Excel workbook.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Workbook.Open event (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.open?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim FileName As String
    Const FILE_TYPE = "*.accdb"
    Dim FolderPath: FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & FILE_TYPE)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(6).Range("File_Path").Value = IIf(FileName = vbNullString, "", FolderPath & FileName)
End Sub
```